# upgrade BlueZ to 5.52 on Raspberry Pi

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

How can I upgrade BlueZ to version 5.52 on a Raspberry Pi?

I tried this, but it seems that the onboard bluetooth is not turned on, so I can't use it:

```
sudo apt purge bluez
(unpack latest BlueZ 5.52 source and cd to it)
./configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --enable-experimental --enable-tools --enable-library --enable-deprecated 
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo systemctl enable bluetooth
```

In order to have the bluetooth deamon running, I have to enable the bluetooth module after each reboot...

after `sudo modprobe bluetooth` the service does run, and `dmsg | grep blue` displays this:

```
[  118.489822] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  118.489929] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  118.489953] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  118.489966] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  118.490008] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  139.315521] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  139.315529] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  139.315544] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

but `hciconfig` gives me no device at all.

What is the missing piece here?

Comment: Bluetooth in RPi is shared with the same UART as the debug. So you need to disable the debug UART in `config.txt`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Part of my answers could be included here: https://www.bluetooth.com/blog/bluez-on-raspberry-pi-update/ In the meantime I installed "over" the official BlueZ apt packages, seems to do the trick.